# Yii2 framework Multi input no mesmo formulário

Tags: input, yii

estou utilizando o widget https://github.com/unclead/yii2-multiple-input
juntamente com o yii2 e estou tendo um erro na hora do commit.

Meu cenário é o seguinte:
Em meu formulário de "catalogos" o usuário pode ao criar o **catálogo**, criar quantos **itens de catálogo** ele quiser. Ou seja, uso no form de criação de catálogo o widget multi input para criação de vários registros do tipo **itens de catalogo**

Estou tendo o seguinte erro:

[image: detalhe do erro]

Código do meu formulário:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'mensagem2')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>


 <?php
        $models = Ponto_venda::find()->asArray()->all();
        $map = ArrayHelper::map($models, 'id_ponto_v', function($model, $defaultValue) {return $model['nome'].' - ' .$model['descricao'];}); 

 ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-11">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'ponto_venda_id_ponto_v')->dropDownList($map) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">
             <a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php?r=ponto_venda%2Fcreate" role="button" style="margin-top:25px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Parte dos itens do catalogo -->
    <?php
        $item_models = Cerveja::find()->asArray()->all();
        $item_map = ArrayHelper::map($item_models, 'id_cerveja', function($item, $defaultValue) {return $item['nome'].' - '.$item['marca_id_marca'];}); 
    ?>      
    <br/>
    <?= $form->field($item, 'Item_catalogo')->widget(MultipleInput::className(), [
        'max' => 4,
        'columns' => [
            [
                'name'  => 'cerveja_id_cerveja',
                'type'  => 'dropDownList',
                'title' => 'Cerveja',
                'items' =>$item_map
            ],

            [
                'name'  => 'preco1',
                'enableError' => true,
                'title' => 'Preço1',
            ],
            [
                'name'  => 'preco2',
                'enableError' => true,
                'title' => 'Preço2',
            ],
            [
                'name'  => 'preco3',
                'enableError' => true,
                'title' => 'Preço3',
            ],
        ]
     ]);
    ?>
    <!-- -->
```

Não consigo entender o porque do erro ao commit dos itens de catálogo sendo que no POST aparentemente ta tudo respeitando as regras de integridades...
Sou novo com o framework... Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta adicionar

```
<input id="form-token" type="hidden" name="<?=Yii::$app->request->csrfParam?>" value="<?=Yii::$app->request->csrfToken?>"/>
```

dentro da tag $form.

Comment: Obrigado por responder amigo, mas acabei optando usar esse outro widget 
https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform

Comment: O importante é que resolveu. Abraços!

Comment: @BrunoCarazato , Que bom que resolveu, mas o problema ali não tem a ver com wdget mas sim com uma chave estrangeira no seu banco de dados.